# __block modifier creates unreadable memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

Now Im developing a banner showing feature in iOS
It's a singleton which shows banner on the upper part of screen when user logs in.

It's basically a shared view with a class method showWithName...

```
@interface XXUserWelcomeBanner ()
{
    UIImageView *logoView;
    UILabel *textLabel;
    CGFloat _width;
}
@end
```

When user calls,  it creates a UIImageView and a UILabel to add on self. And animates itself onto the screen.

```
+ (XXUserWelcomeBanner *)shared {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static XXUserWelcomeBanner *userWelcomBanner;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        userWelcomBanner = [[XXUserWelcomeBanner alloc] init];
    });
    return userWelcomBanner;
}

+ (void)showWithUserName:(NSString *)userID andLogo:(UIImage * _Nullable)logo {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self shared] createWithName:userID andLogo:logo];
    });
}
```

So there's this other bug I just found that causes this method to be called twice and **on the second time it shows only the UIImageView**.

And I don't understand why that's happening. 
Because the UIImageView and UILabel won't be created twice.

Here's more code.

```
#pragma mark - private
- (void)createWithName:(NSString *)name andLogo:(UIImage * _Nullable)logo {
    self.opaque = NO;
    self.alpha = 0.9;
    self.backgroundColor = COLOR(0xfcfcfc);

    //    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    //        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.secondarySystemBackgroundColor;
    //    }
    CGSize labelSize = CGSizeZero;


    if (logoView == nil) {
        if (logo != nil) {
            logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logo];

            [self addSubview:logoView];
        } else {
            NSString *imagePath = [XXUtility pathForResourceNamed:@"Logo" withExtension:@"png"];
            UIImage *imageToAdd = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
            logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageToAdd];
            [self addSubview:logoView];
        }
    }

    if (textLabel == nil) {
        textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        NSString * labelString = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"welcom banner", @"userInterface", [XXUtility bundleForStrings], @"Dear %@, welcome into game", @"user welcome banner text"), name];
        labelSize = [labelString sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : textLabel.font}];
        textLabel.text = labelString;
        [self addSubview:textLabel];
    }
    NSLog(@"XXUserWelcomeBanner Label size is %f x %f", labelSize.height, labelSize.width);
    [self bannerSizeWithLabelSize:labelSize];
    CGFloat bannerHeight = self.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat bannerWidth = self.frame.size.width;

    CGFloat logoHeight = bannerHeight * 0.45;
    CGFloat logoWidth = logoHeight;
    CGFloat logoXPos = (bannerWidth - logoWidth - labelSize.width) / 2;
    CGFloat logoYPos = (bannerHeight - logoHeight) / 2;
    CGFloat labelHeight = labelSize.height;
    CGFloat labelWidth = labelSize.width;
    CGFloat labelXPos = logoXPos + logoWidth + 5;
    CGFloat labelYPos = (bannerHeight - labelHeight) / 2;

    logoView.frame = CGRectMake(logoXPos, logoYPos, logoWidth, logoHeight);
    textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(labelXPos, labelYPos, labelWidth, labelHeight);

    [self bannerShow];
}

- (void)bannerSizeWithLabelSize:(CGSize)lSize {
    _width = 40 + lSize.width + 5;
    CGFloat height = 40;
    CGFloat xPosition = ScreenWidth * 1/2 - _width * 1/2;
    CGFloat yPosition = - height;

    self.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, _width, height);
}

- (void)bannerShow {
    UIViewController *vc;
    if ([TOP_VIEWCONTROLLER respondsToSelector:@selector(topViewController)]) {
        vc = [TOP_VIEWCONTROLLER topViewController];
    } else {
        vc = TOP_VIEWCONTROLLER;
    }

    [vc.view addSubview:self];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        CGFloat height = 40;
        CGFloat xPos = ScreenWidth * 1/2 - self->_width * 1/2;
        CGFloat yPos = height * 1/3 + KiPhoneXSafeAreaDValue;

        self.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, self->_width, height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

                CGFloat height = 40;
                CGFloat xPosition = ScreenWidth * 1/2 - self->_width * 1/2;
                CGFloat yPosition = - height;

                self.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, self->_width, height);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [self bannerDestroy];
                self.alpha = 0;
            }];
        });
    }];
}


- (void)bannerDestroy {
    [logoView removeFromSuperview];
    [textLabel removeFromSuperview];
    logoView = nil;
    textLabel = nil;
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    //
    NSLog(@"uiview dealloc");
}

/*
 // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
 // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
 // Drawing code
 }
 */

@end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the declaration of `labelSize`. I am struggling to see why you need a singleton at all here.

Comment: Can you add more code? It is hard to understand how do you use `labelSize`.

Comment: If you call `createWithName:andLogo:` with different values you cannot put it in `init` in your singleton.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that `createWithName:andLogo:` is calling more than once in your app. I guess you call it with different arguments, that's why it should not be inside `dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{ });`. But you can optimise `XXUserWelcomeBanner`'s `init`:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [self addSubview:logoView];
        textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [self addSubview:textLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In `createWithName:andLogo:` you will have the following:

```
if (logo != nil) {
    logoView.image = logo;
} else {
    NSString *imagePath = [XXUtility pathForResourceNamed:@"Logo" withExtension:@"png"];
    UIImage *imageToAdd = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    logoView.image = imageToAdd;
}

NSString * labelString = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"welcom banner", @"userInterface", [XXUtility bundleForStrings], @"Dear %@, welcome into game", @"user welcome banner text"), name];
CGSize labelSize = [labelString sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : textLabel.font}];
textLabel.text = labelString;
```